# What are the available keywords in OleDB for mrOleDB.Provider.2?

Tags: c#, oledb

I am working on a tool which needs to autocomplete keywords of an OleDB command.
By keywords I mean `SELECT UPDATE FROM WHERE` etc.
I've been searching google for quite a while now without being successful in finding a list of all avaiable commands.
The key problem here is that OleDB does not use all the standard sql commands so my list would be incomplete if I am just going to use those.

So final question, just like in the title: What are the available keywords in OleDB commands for a mrOleDB.Provider.2?

Comment: that is dependant on the provider. Not all OLEDBs are equal

Comment: I am using mrOleDB.Provider.2 as provider

Comment: I don't know what that driver is. A google doesn't help. I'd consult the documentation for that provider, if any exists. Or consider a more standard provider to query whatever your querying.

Comment: It is an IBM provider which I definitly need, biggest problem at this point was, that I was not aware that there are more than one oledb provider (duh). IBMs documentation on that is huge, but as soon as I found what I need I will provide the answer.

Comment: It seems to be the IBM SPSS Data Collection Model provider. You might find the info you need here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVQG_6.0.1/com.spss.ddl/mroledb_ref_overview.htm?lang=ca  OR http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVQG_6.0.1/com.spss.ddl/sql_summary.htm?lang=ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to Paul and Liam which helped me to find my solution.
The available keywords for the IBM SPSS Collection Model provider can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVQG_6.0.1/com.spss.ddl/sql_reservedwords.htm?lang=en).

> ### Reserved Keywords
>
> The following table lists the reserved keywords used in the Data Model
>   SQL syntax. Both the uppercase and lowercase versions of these
>   reserved keywords can be used as question names, variable names, and
>   as part of a full name. For example, "Table" can be used as the name
>   of a question nested inside a loop as well as the name of a simple
>   question. The words that can be used as part of a full name are marked
>   with an asterisk (*).
>
> ```
> Add   Desc    Select
> All   Double  Set*
> Alter Drop    Stdev
> As    Exec    Sum
> Asc   From    Table*
> Avg   Group*  Text
> Base  Having  Truncate
> Boolean   Insert  Update
> By*   Into    Value
> Categorical   Level   Values
> Column*   Long    Where
> Count Max With*
> Create    Min  
> Date  Object   
> Default   On*  
> Delete    Order*
> ```